# Unable create ext4 filesystem under LUKS

Tags: filesystems, mount, luks, mkfs

I've successfully created a LUKS drive from a 32Mb USB flash drive. However when I write an ext4 filesystem to it I am unable to mount the result, or even run `fsck` or `dumpe2fs` etc.

The drive shows up under `lsblk` as

```
sda           8:0    1   31M  0 disk
└─luks      253:0    0   15M  0 crypt
```

I'm then writing the filesystem with `sudo mkfs.ext4 -v /dev/mapper/luks`, which produces

```
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
fs_types for mke2fs.conf resolution: 'ext4', 'small'
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
3840 inodes, 3840 blocks
192 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4194304
1 block group
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
3840 inodes per group

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (1024 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

###### Output from various commands

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          3
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           1f30e940-4144-4980-a32a-4f1b78a46fc5
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
        offset: 16777216 [bytes]
        length: (whole device)
        cipher: aes-xts-plain64
        sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
        Key:        512 bits
        Priority:   normal
        Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
        Cipher key: 512 bits
        PBKDF:      argon2i
        Time cost:  4
        Memory:     187471
        Threads:    4
        Salt:       5c c4 28 e0 bc f6 7f df b2 1c 77 b6 fa f3 f1 bc
                    48 66 fc 56 e3 5c e5 13 cc af 1d 52 ec df fc 93
        AF stripes: 4000
        AF hash:    sha256
        Area offset:32768 [bytes]
        Area length:258048 [bytes]
        Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
        Hash:       sha256
        Iterations: 18853
        Salt:       62 8a b7 2c 4d 74 d3 6b 46 c2 9b 34 e2 d6 5c 3d
                    06 12 ee a7 5b b0 81 1f d0 99 19 b6 4f de 5c 77
        Digest:     c2 71 c1 d5 de 16 d9 cc 8c 15 f2 34 21 42 3a a3
                    24 d1 82 26 cd ab f9 98 0c 0a 68 7a 35 e2 3d a9
```

^The `Subsystem:      (no subsystem)` line is worrying

```
$ sudo mount -v /dev/mapper/luks /media/luks
mount: /media/luks: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/luks, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/mapper/luks
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/luks
...
```

^`fsck.ext2` suggests to me that it can't tell the filesystem

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/mapper/luks
dumpe2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/luks
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

All of these suggest to me that the filesystem hasn't been created correctly, however from what I can tell even a measly 15Mb should be enough space and I'm not sure what else could be the problem

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the filesystem part. It might be worth sharing how you've created the LUKS partition. You have opened the LUKS partition (decrypted its access), haven't you...?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. You should run `badblocks` in write mode on the device.

Comment: @HaukeLaging aha that looks like it, the latter half of the blocks are bad

Comment: That would get you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware problem. You should run `badblocks` in write mode on the device.

Another option would be

- to create a small image file (a few 100 MiB)
- put a loop device upon it
- create the filesystem in it
- copy the image file to the (first part of the) device
- compare the image file to the respective part of the device

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/imagefile bs=1M count=100

losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/imagefile

mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0

blockdev --getsz /dev/loop0
204800

dd if=imagefile of=/dev/mapper/luks

sha1sum imagefile 
aaafc117548aaebef3dbb5f4a609022e386192b6  imagefile

dd if=/dev/mapper/luks count=204800 | sha1sum 
204800+0 Datensätze ein
204800+0 Datensätze aus
aaafc117548aaebef3dbb5f4a609022e386192b6  -
```